# Sprechen and les-trace

Tags: support

Here is a question which is vaguely comprehending, but bordering on nonsense: [Is the Chern-Simons integral of gauge fields over black hole singularities zero?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33082/is-the-chern-simons-integral-of-gauge-fields-over-black-hole-singularities-zero)

It gets a total nonsense answer and mutual upvoting. Are Sprechen and les-trace independent accounts? This is a flag for mods, I don't need an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of these accounts has voting privileges as yet, so the votes are coming from elsewhere.<sup>1</sup>

The account *could* be sockpuppets, but I don't feel we have enough evidence to act: we don't want to do something drastic to real users.

---

<sup>1</sup> There are times when I think we have some users on the site who vote up anything they don't understand.